# Pi 2B not producing picture on screen

Tags: pi-2

My Pi 2B will start, showing the rainbow startup picture. After that, nothing else happens. It looks like the Pi is reading the SD card, but it has been doing this for a while. What do I do?

Comment: If no text appears on the screen why do you think it is reading the SD card? Are any of the leds flashing and if so in what pattern? How did you prepare the SD card?

Comment: one beep... beep beep beep beep... one beep... beep beep beep beep. that's what it's doing. the led colours are permanent red, and the green flickering in the pattern above. i formatted the SD like it says in the QSG.

Comment: Your Pi is beeping?

Comment: no noise, flickering. sorry for that 'beep' example

Comment: It appears that your Pi can't find the files needed to boot, can you redownload and flash the card, even better try a different card.

Comment: @SteveRobillard, maybe it's an R2Pi2, which might be beeping ;)

Comment: @Ghanima then threaten it with a C3PiO! 8-)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to reformat and reinstall the OS to your SD card by following these steps:

**For Windows**

- Download the SD formatting tool: [https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/eula_windows/](https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter/sd-memory-card-formatter-for-windows-download/)
- Make sure you enable the Format size adjustment [image: SD] [image: SD2]
- Check that the name of the SD matches with the ons in the SD formatting tool I.E.: "F"
- Click the format button

[image: SD3]

**Mac**

- Download the SD formatting tool: [https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/eula_mac/](https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter/sd-memory-card-formatter-for-mac-download/)
- Install it.
- Select the overwrite format option.[image: SD_MAC]
- Check that the name of the SD matches with the on in the SD formatting tool
- Click the format button

**Linux**

- Open gparted (If not installed type in terminal: `sudo apt-get install gparted` [image: Install gparted]
- Format as FAT
  [image: Format as FAT]

**These steps are the same on ALL devices (Windows, Mac, Linux)**

- Extract the files from the NOOBS zip:[image: Extracted_NOOBS_Files]
- Select all these files and copy them over to the SD card (Can take a while)
- Insert SD into Pi and give it keyboard, mouse, LAN(internet), and last power.

If everything is done correct the Pi should boot into the NOOBS OS where you can select and download OS versions (Dual boot also works)

[image: NOOBS]
<sub>(source: [raspberrypi.org](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/images/noobs.png))</sub>

**After installing:**
You will need to expand the filesystem by going to the terminal and type: `sudo raspi-config` and select the first option:"Expand filesystem":
[image: raspi-config]
<sub>(source: [raspberrypi.org](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/images/raspi-config.png))</sub>

More info about raspi-config: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/raspi-config.md

**Troubleshooting**

If your screen keeps blank, you may need to select the correct display mode by pressing a number on the keyboard:

1. HDMI mode - this is the default display mode.
2. HDMI safe mode - select this mode if you are using the HDMI
   connector and cannot see anything on screen when the Pi has booted.
3. Composite PAL mode - select either this mode or composite NTSC mode
   if you are using the composite RCA video connector.
4. Composite NTSC mode

I got the information from the "INSTRUCTIONS-README.txt" file inside the NOOBS files.
[http://pastebin.com/d61ttv1F](https://pastebin.com/d61ttv1F)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the correct image (pi2 not pi B).

Also check if your power supply is up to the task.

A lot of trouble can be traced back to low power beeing deliverd to your Pi (also due to USB extention cables etc)

Answer (score 0):

Actually those *blinking* LEDs could be trying to tell you something - look up those Green LED flashes on the Elinux.org site's [R-Pi Troubleshooting](http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Green_LED_blinks_in_a_specific_pattern).